Unknown control: navigationdrawer
I'm trying to add a drawer, however I can't understand why it always shows as unknown control.

app.py:
from flet import *
from pages.home import Home

class Main(UserControl):
    def __init__(self, page: Page):
        super().__init__()
        self.page = page
        self.init_helper()

    def init_helper(self):
        self.page.on_route_change = self.on_route_change
        self.page.go('/home')

    def on_route_change(self, route):
        # Instanciar as páginas ROUTE
        new_page = {
            "/home": Home,
        }[self.page.route](self.page)

        self.page.views.clear()
        self.page.views.append(
            View(route,
                [new_page]
                )
        )

        self.page.update()

def main(page: Page):
    page.title = "Lta Music"
    page.add(Main(page))

app(target=main, assets_dir='assets')

home.py:
from flet import *

class Home(UserControl):
    def __init__(self, page: Page):
        super().__init__()
        self.page = page
        self.expand = True

        # Iniciar configurações
        self.observer(None)  # Chamar o observer com None

        # Adicionar um listener para mudanças de tamanho da tela
        self.page.on_resize = self.observer

        #########################################################
        #   Abaixo escrever os widgets (contúdos)               #
        #########################################################

        # Criar um NavigationDrawer com estado inicial como fechado
        self.drawer = NavigationDrawer(
            open=False,
            controls=[
                Container(height=12),
                NavigationDrawerDestination(
                    label="Item 1",
                    icon=icons.DOOR_BACK_DOOR_OUTLINED,
                    selected_icon_content=Icon(icons.DOOR_BACK_DOOR),
                ),
                Divider(thickness=2),
                NavigationDrawerDestination(
                    icon_content=Icon(icons.MAIL_OUTLINED),
                    label="Item 2",
                    selected_icon=icons.MAIL,
                ),
                NavigationDrawerDestination(
                    icon_content=Icon(icons.PHONE_OUTLINED),
                    label="Item 3",
                    selected_icon=icons.PHONE,
                ),
            ],
        )

        def show_drawer(e):
            self.drawer.open = not self.drawer.open
            self.page.update()
            print('que merda')

        # Criar o AppBar personalizado
        self.appbar = Container(
            content=Row(
                controls=[
                    IconButton(icon=icons.MENU_OUTLINED, on_click=show_drawer, icon_color=colors.WHITE),
                    Text("Reprodutor de música", style="titleLarge", color=colors.WHITE),
                    IconButton(icon=icons.PALETTE_OUTLINED, on_click=self.toggle_theme, icon_color=colors.WHITE),
                    IconButton(icon=icons.SEARCH, on_click=self.search_action, icon_color=colors.WHITE)
                ],
                alignment="spaceBetween",
                vertical_alignment="center"
            ),
            bgcolor=colors.TRANSPARENT,
            padding=10
        )

        # Criar um Tabs
        self.homeTabs = Tabs(
            selected_index=1,
            divider_color= colors.GREY,
            divider_height=0.1,
            indicator_color=colors.PURPLE,
            label_color="white",
            unselected_label_color="grey",
            scrollable= True,
            animation_duration=300,
            tabs=[
                Tab(
                    adaptive= True,
                    text="Faixas",
                    content=Container(
                        content=Text(" Aqui vai ser inserido uma lista com todas as músicas", style="titleLarge", color=colors.WHITE), alignment=alignment.center
                    ),
                ),
                Tab(
                    adaptive= True,
                    text="Lista de reprodução",
                    content=Container(
                        content=Text(" Aqui vai aparecer as listas de reprodução", style="titleLarge", color=colors.WHITE), alignment=alignment.center
                    ),
                ),
                Tab(
                    adaptive= True,
                    text="Pastas",
                    content=Container(
                        content=Text(" Aqui vai poder selecionar a pasta origem das músicas", style="titleLarge", color=colors.WHITE), alignment=alignment.center
                    ),
                ),
                Tab(
                    adaptive= True,
                    text="Teste 1",
                    content=Container(
                        content=Text(" Aqui vai poder selecionar a pasta origem das músicas", style="titleLarge", color=colors.WHITE), alignment=alignment.center
                    ),
                ),
                Tab(
                    adaptive= True,
                    text="Teste 2",
                    content=Container(
                        content=Text(" Aqui vai poder selecionar a pasta origem das músicas", style="titleLarge", color=colors.WHITE), alignment=alignment.center
                    ),
                ),
                Tab(
                    adaptive= True,
                    text="Teste 3",
                    content=Container(
                        content=Text(" Aqui vai poder selecionar a pasta origem das músicas", style="titleLarge", color=colors.WHITE), alignment=alignment.center
                    ),
                ),
            ],
            width=400,
            height=400,
        )

        # Atribuição de widgets ao content com self.widget
        self.content = Column(
            controls=[
                self.homeTabs,
            ]
        )

        # Criar um Container com fundo gradiente
        self.background = Container(
            content=Column(
                controls=[
                    self.appbar,
                    self.content
                ],
                expand=True,
                spacing=0
            ),
            expand=True,
            gradient=LinearGradient(
                begin=alignment.top_left,
                end=Alignment(0.1, 1.5),
                colors=["#1c2454","#342c5b" ,"#64244b"]  # Cores do gradiente
            )
        )

        # Adicionar os objetos ao controle principal
        self.controls.append(self.background)
        self.controls.append(self.drawer)
        self.page.update()
        print("Controles ativos: ", self.controls)

    #########################################################
    #   Abaixo escrever as funções/métodos (def)            #
    #########################################################
    def observer(self, e=None):
        larg_tela = self.page.width
        alt_tela = self.page.height
        if larg_tela < 768:
            tipo_tela = "MOBILE"
        elif larg_tela < 1000:
            tipo_tela = "TABLET"
        else:
            tipo_tela = "DESKTOP"

        os_name = self.page.platform
        print("largura: ", larg_tela, "\naltura: ", alt_tela, "\ndispositivo: ", tipo_tela, "\nsistema: ", os_name)
        return larg_tela, alt_tela, tipo_tela, os_name

    def toggle_theme(self, e):
        print("Toggle theme action triggered")

    def search_action(self, e):
        print("Search action triggered")

    def more_action(self, e):
        print("More action triggered")

    def go_home(self, e):
        print("Home clicked")

    def go_settings(self, e):
        print("Settings clicked")

    def go_about(self, e):
        print("About clicked")

Print message:

Controles ativos:  [Container(expand=1), NavigationDrawer(open=False)]

I have tried enlisting the control in several ways, but it remains an unknown control. I am using the following command line:
flet run -r -p 8551 --android /home/felipereis/Dev/11-ltamusic/app.py

References:

NavigationDrawer
Flet Tutorial - Make Navigation Drawer [ Official Flet Team ]

